# UITextField inside of custom UITableView is nil in Swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a UITableView in my current project. Each cell is an object of custom class DecisionItem, which implements UITableViewCell. Inside each of these DecisionItems should be a UITextField named "descriptionBox". However, each time I run this app, descriptionBox keeps showing up as nil. Why is this?

This is what shows up in the console, as you can see, descriptionBox is nil:

[image]

This is my prototype cell:

[image: prototypecells]

My cells show up entirely blank while running the app:

[image]

These are things that I have made sure I've done:

1. Yes, DecisionItem has an IBOutlet variable named descriptionBox that is connected to the UITextField in the prototype cell.

[image]

2. Yes, I set the prototype cell's class to the custom class DecisionItem

[image]

3. Yes, I cast the cell to DecisionItem in the cellForRowAt function

[image]

4. Yes, my reuse identifiers are all correct.

What could be causing this error?

Comment: Did you try to add in the end of the cell as?
Like so:
 let  cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell") as! SomeTableViewCell

Answer (score 0):

In your storyboard on the left side scene hierarchy right click on the DecisionItem cell and hover over descriptionBox to make sure it highlights the correct text field in the storyboard. If you see a yellow warning sign click the X and relink it.